# What online tool do you use to automate translation of .arb files?

Tags: flutter, translation, arb

Do you know any good tools to support the translation of .arb files?

It's a standard for Flutter and since Google Translator Toolkit will be sunset soon (https://support.google.com/translatortoolkit/answer/9462068) we're searching for a good solution to translate/gather our translations

Comment: Check https://github.com/dart-lang/intl_translation/issues/74. Maybe upvote to increase priority.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds good. I also added issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40662

Comment: attranslate is another new tool that automates the translation of ARB-files: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate In contrast to one-off services, attranslate is more geared towards a continuous translation process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit (June 2020): There's great new open source project called [Arbify](https://github.com/Arbify/Arbify). This is a self-hosted tool to manage multiple translation projects focused on Flutter. You can edit arb files and fetch them via [Dart package tool](https://pub.dev/packages/arbify).

Aside from that some services like POEditor have announced basic support for ARB too.

---

At the moment the best support for arb files is on [Localizely](https://localizely.com/). However, this is a paid service and has strict limits on a free version. It allows to export arb translation files with plurals and placeholder support. It doesn't support genders, though.

There is also [one simple web editor](https://jamesblasco.github.io/arb_editor/master/#/) and one desktop editor ([Babel](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit)) that support arb files.

Comment: Note that [one simple web editor](https://jamesblasco.github.io/arb_editor/master/#/) is no longer maintained and was never finished to a release standard.

Comment: Thanks, I added Arbify as a new alternative

Comment: I have today bit experimented with Localizely and it seems to support Genders. https://localizely.com/flutter-arb/

Comment: Arbify is no longer in active development

Answer (score 2):

Crowdin supports .arb:

https://support.crowdin.com/supported-formats/

It is also able to pull the data from a Git repo and send Pull Requests on GitHub.

However, when I used it in 2018 there was a problem of `@@last_modified` attribute being updated without any other changes to the translation files, causing lots of churn in PRs.  By that time, they were reluctant to improve the situation (based on email conversation with their support), so we resorted to manual edits.

Answer (score 1):

https://localise.biz/ allows 2000 translations. Which I assume are 1000 strings in 2 languages or ~666 strings in 3 languages and so on. Which is more than https://localizely.com/ 150 strings